# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - While using medusa ga

Tags: java, javafx, medusa

I'm using the `Gauge` from [Medusa](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa) to show battery percentage for my JavaFX project. After some iteration of updating I'm getting this error.

Here is the error I'm getting.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3481)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.GrowableDataBuffer.putObject(GrowableDataBuffer.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext.writeText(GraphicsContext.java:782)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext.fillText(GraphicsContext.java:1648)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.tools.Helper.drawRadialTickMarks(Helper.java:971)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.skins.GaugeSkin.redraw(GaugeSkin.java:1095)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.skins.GaugeSkinBase.handleEvents(GaugeSkinBase.java:60)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.skins.GaugeSkin.handleEvents(GaugeSkin.java:305)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.skins.GaugeSkinBase.lambda$registerListeners$2(GaugeSkinBase.java:52)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.skins.GaugeSkinBase$$Lambda$203/0x00000001002c06c0.onUpdateEvent(Unknown Source)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge.fireUpdateEvent(Gauge.java:5887)
    at eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge.setBarColor(Gauge.java:3492)
    at com.log9materials.utilities.ui_utilities.FXUtilities$16.run(FXUtilities.java:388)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$104/0x0000000100143218.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:776)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$103/0x0000000100141fc8.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$92/0x0000000100130d10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my code.

```java
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (gaugeIndicator != null) {
            gaugeIndicator.setValue(doubleValue);
            if (doubleValue <= 10) {
                gaugeIndicator.setBarColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (doubleValue <= 20) {
                gaugeIndicator.setBarColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (doubleValue <= 80) {
                gaugeIndicator.setBarColor(Color.ORANGE);
            } else {
                gaugeIndicator.setBarColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could post a [mcve]?